# $('#options\[0\]\[description\]').val("Helloworld"); does not work

Tags: jquery

I want to insert value `Hello world` to input text which has id `options[0][description]`

But this does not work

```
$('#options\[0\]\[description\]').val("Helloworld");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, `\\` is the escape sequence.

```
$('#options\\[0\\]\\[description\\]').val("Helloworld");
```

[Category: Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Comment: works. but i dont understand why do I need two "\" ? here it needs only one \ http://jsfiddle.net/7RJtf/1/

Comment: @John, in the fiddle you link to, the replacement value is `"\\$1"`, which would change `]` to `\\]`, with **two** slashes, keep in mind that the replacement value is the two literal characters \\  then  $1 which is a reference to the matched substring. The first \  in `"\\$1"` is **not** an escape character. I feel like that might have been your misconception

Answer (score 0):

You have escape charaters `\` so you must add another one before each one

```
$('#options\\[0\\]\\[description\]').val("Helloworld");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koqodv4a/)

```
$('#options\\[0\\]\\[description\\]').val("Helloworld");
```